# Using LIMIT clause in Sybase

Tags: php, sybase, sql-limit

in MySQL I am able to use LIMIT clause but not in the sybase. I have found a lot of question and answers on the net but I can't find what I want. I have tried this

```
    SELECT TOP 5 * FROM Employees ORDER BY Surname;
```

but sybase throws and error.it says incorrect syntax near 5. I have also tried this one

```
SELECT BOTTOM 5 * FROM
(SELECT TOP 15 * FROM someTable
ORDER BYorderColumns DESC)
```

also not working. and also this one:

```
SET ROWCOUNT 60
DECLARE @name VARCHAR
SELECT @name = name
FROM user
WHERE something = $something
ORDER BY date ASC

SET ROWCOUNT 20
SELECT *
FROM user
WHERE name >= @name
```

this is not working since I don't have any ID number in the table, but only name which has varchar data type. Any ideas guys?
Thank you so much in advance.

Comment: anybody? please help me...

Comment: What is your sybase? ASA, ASE, IQ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure which sybase do you use, but this:

```
SELECT TOP 5 * FROM Employees ORDER BY Surname
```

will work on `ASE`.

You can also try this way:

```
SELECT TOP(5) * FROM Employees ORDER BY Surname;
```

Comment: I am using Sybase v15. TOP is now working, no problem, but once i put bottom, i got syntax error.

Comment: @Bizarre `bottom` is not valid on sybase ase. With this information I can't help you now. Show us your example data, and what result do you expect.

Comment: since bottom is not working, I have changed the way i'm displaying it.I am using LIMIT in MySQL to do a pagination, so i would like to achieve same task with sybase. but since it cannot be done, I have retrieve all records from database, and sort them using PHP stuffs...